# How to create role based header menu control in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

My application has 4 users and each user has different roles. Based on user logged in I need to show/hide header menus. For some users header menus may be common.

How to achieve this using Spring MVC (best practise) ? Can anyone help me !!!

Comment: Are you using a template framework? (JSP, Velocity, Freemarker) If you are using a template you can add the user's roles to the model that is passed to the template. Then in the template build up the menu base on the roles.

Answer (score 0):

You can show/hide menu/menu items according to user credentials.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by many way's.

**Way 1 :** You can create dynamic menu based on Spring Security TagLib.

Step 1 : declared security taglib in your JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

Step 2 : define like given below. This content will only be visible to users who have the "admin" or "manager" authority in their list of GrantedAuthoritys.

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('MANAGER') ">
<li>
<a href="/admin">Location List</a>
</li>
</sec:authorize>
```

**Way 2 :** You can create dynamic menu based on role using .

Step 1 : include core library using <%@taglib> in top of the jsp page.

Step 2 : set role after logging user then you can check condition for role like

```
<c:test admin!=null>
     menu links for admin
 </c:test>
 <c:test user!=null>
     menu links for user
 </c:test>
```